# Shader script nodes have no parameters

Tags: scripting, node-editor, shaders, osl

I am trying to do my first OSL shader script. No matter what I do, even when using all the examples, when I add a node for my shader none of the parameters show up as node inputs/outputs as I have read they should.

What am I doing wrong, why don't they show up? (Blender 2.8)

```
shader noise(
    float Time = 1.0,
    point Point = P,
    output float Cell = 0.0,
    output color Perlin = 0.8,
    output color UPerlin = 0.8,
    output color Simplex = 0.8,
    output color USimplex = 0.8)
{
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Blender has a few oddities, including:

1. Script need to be reloaded/refreshed when changed/loading via the little double-arrow button in the node block next to the filename. Use that when/if loading/changing.
2. If there are ANY errors or oddities in your script (at least in Blender 2.8) - this will result in your node not changing to reflect the *current* script it's pointing at. i.e. It won't give you an error, but when changing the node block from one script to another - it simply wont change. (Button above can help your diagnose errors)
3. FYI - If not shades to not actually work - make *sure* you are *not* using GPU rendering. OSL works with CPU rendering, only. In addition - make sure "open shading language" is checked below the CPU option (in the Scene property under "Render Engine").

[image]